# Make a rigged character's head rotate in sync with a quaternion in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a face detection app, and I want a character's head to rotate according to the detected face's pose.

I've managed to get the rotation of the detected face in the form of a quaternion, but I'm unsure about how I'm supposed to translate the data from the quaternion into 3D points for the reference points of the rigged character which I believe will decide the rotation.

Let's say I have this character: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ2oP.png

One solution could be to just cut off the head and make it an own object and then set the rotation of that object according to the quaternion, but I don't want that. I want an intact character.

Is it possible to move the reference points in the head with the data from a quaternion? Or have I gotten it wrong how rigged characters turn their heads? I haven't animated before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply rotation to a single bone. Get that bone in your script. Keep a var in your class to store the last quaternion in and every update, compare it to that and rotate by the different. I don't have the actual editor here but try this psuedocode.

```
class NeckRotator {
    public GameObject Neck;
    private Quaternion LastFace;


    void Start(){
        LastFace = Neck.transform.Rotation;
    }

    void Update(){
        var DetectedFace = ... // Whatever you do to get this
        var Change = Quaternion.Inverse(DetectedFace) * LastFace; // Found this online real quick
        Neck.Rotate(Change);
        LastFace = Neck.transform.Rotation;
    }
}
```

I've done something like that before to rotate a neck of an NPC to look at a player. It should work for your deal as well.

Comment: Wait, what are a and b supposed to be?

Comment: My bad. It's DetectedFace and LastFace. Though that might be opposite. Also, LastFace should be the Quaternion of the neck at the last update. I think you get it something like this, right?

Comment: I didn't need to calculate the inverse. I could just set the rotation of the bone with the quaternion I had. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! When I did that personally, it caused issues when something else caused the rotation of the bone to change. The bone wouldn't turn along with the rest of the body like I wanted it to. If you run into the same issue, you could try this anyway. :)